# Create a Tree in php mysql with specific conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a MLM project, But the problem is, I don't have proper logic to built a tree like this.
i have uploaded the screen shot of tree here, please view it, how tree should be built

[image]

i  have a form where user will enter the referal_id at the time of sign up, and the new user should get inserted into the referal_id(S) tree in the same way as tree is growing.

Please help with some algorithm or some good code, that can solve my problem :-(

Comment: I think the best way to do this is to work with arrays in arrays. and then write a recursive function to get the values.

Comment: can you pls help me with an example? i spent like ages, but found no solution. :-(

Comment: Well http://snipplr.com/view/22864/ here you have an example how you build the tree.

Comment: @Vince: don't answer questions in comments.

Comment: @Nikc I don't provide an answer I just say, look here, you will find the answer there.

Comment: @Vince: providing a link to an answer in the comments, is providing an answer in the comments. Internal SO links are a different topic, since they would (most likely) have been answered properly. (Should be accompanied by a close-vote, though.) By not providing your answer properly, the community has no method of evaluating the quality of your answer, nor build upon it.

Comment: Ok, I'll post it then :)

Answer (score 0):

http://snipplr.com/view/22864

Here you have an example how you build a tree in php.